# Internal Server Error when deploying Laravel using docker & reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel apps using docker. But got internal server error when accessing the url.

I have 2 server, one is for public ip & reverse proxy, and the second is where the Laravel apps located.
Let's just say that the first one is 10.0.0.12 and the second is 10.0.0.81. I'm using IP & Port for testing purpose

In 10.0.0.12 I have reverse proxy using nginx, proxied the connection to 10.0.0.81

```
server {
        listen 8666;
        server_name 10.0.0.12;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.81:8555;

        }
}
```

And this is my Dockerfile inside the Laravel project:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl bcmath gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html/laravel-cms

COPY . .

RUN composer install --no-scripts

RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 80 di dalam container
EXPOSE 80

# Set permission pada Apache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/laravel-cms

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

This is for Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel-app
    container_name: laravel_cms-container
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8555:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/laravel-cms
    networks:
      - laravel

networks:
  laravel:
```

After configuring all of that, I'm running docker build and docker up command. Up to this point, there's no error. But when I'm accessing the url in the browser I got message like this:

```
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.81:5555/", host: "10.0.0.12:8666" 2023/12/20 15:42:01 [error] 178771#178771: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: 10.0.0.12
```

Did I do anything wrong? What can I do to fix this? Sorry but this is my first time using Docker container. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do what the error message tells you. Read the server error log.

Comment: But why do you proxy twice?

Comment: My bad, I'm already directed the proxy to docker container but got this error: `request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.81:5555/", host: "10.0.0.12:8666"
2023/12/20 15:42:01 [error] 178771#178771: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: 10.0.0.12`

Comment: Does your upstream actually listen?

Comment: @vidarlo Sorry but how to check it? Usually if I'm only using apache I can listen the port using ports.conf file. But if using docker how to do that?

Comment: You specify a upstream server `http://10.0.0.81:8555`. Is that server working and replying? Typically your upstream in a docker scenario should be the service name...